# Azure Service Bus - Receive messages continuously

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

I want to move from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus library to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library, because this one is more actual.
I have problem in my Rest Api (.NET) where I need to continously receive messages from Service Bus queue.

In previous library there was a Method RegisterMessageHandler(Func<Message,CancellationToken,Task>, MessageHandlerOptions)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.registermessagehandler?view=azure-dotnet

that worked just fine for me. In new library (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) I can't find one to do same thing.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this? And I don't mean going back to previous library ;)

Comment: Why are you not using [ServiceBusTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp)?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - I meant Rest Api (my Function App reads from IotHub and, after calculation, sends data to Service Bus queue and there Rest Api should receive it)

Comment: ok, but it still makes more sense to me to use a ServiceBusTrigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an equivalent in the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK called  `ServiceBusProcessor`. See [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample04_Processor.md) how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work fine after local tests. Time to run it on dev environment.