# Azure service bus read all messages at once using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` nuget package to work with Azure service bus. We have created a topic and a subscription. The subscription has 100+ messages. We want to read all the message and continue to read message as they arrive.

`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package (deprecated now) provided `RegisterMessageHandler` which use to process every incoming message. I am not able to find similar option under `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` nuget package.

I am able to read one message at a time but I have to call `await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();` every time manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive multiple messages (a batch), you should use [`ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.receivemessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet) (not plural, not singular 'message'). This method will return whatever number of messages it can send back. To ensure you retrieve all 100+ messages, you'll need to loop until no messages are available.

If you'd like to use a processor, that's also available in the new SDK. See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732107/59563).

Comment: While this answer solve the problem partially. I am looking for a message handler / callback type of function, Which should automatically run when we have message in the topic/queue.

Comment: Have you opened the link? It literally pointed to the code for the processor you posted 

Comment: Hard to say why I missed the link :(

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @gaurav Mantri, I used [ServiceBusProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessor?view=azure-dotnet) class to implement event based model for processing messages

```
 public async Task ReceiveAll()
    {
        string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sb-test-today.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=manage;SharedAccessKey=8e+6SWp3skB3Aedsadsadasdwz5DU=;";
        string topicName = "topicone";
        string subscriptionName = "subone";
        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        });

        var options = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
        {
            // By default or when AutoCompleteMessages is set to true, the processor will complete the message after executing the message handler
            // Set AutoCompleteMessages to false to [settle messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock) on your own.
            // In both cases, if the message handler throws an exception without settling the message, the processor will abandon the message.
            AutoCompleteMessages = false,

            // I can also allow for multi-threading
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
        };

        await using ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, options);

        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);

        // we can evaluate application logic and use that to determine how to settle the message.
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }

    public Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        // the error source tells me at what point in the processing an error occurred
        Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorSource);
        // the fully qualified namespace is available
        Console.WriteLine(args.FullyQualifiedNamespace);
        // as well as the entity path
        Console.WriteLine(args.EntityPath);
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```