# Azure Service Bus Receive Messages continuously when ever new message placed in web application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web

My Requirement as below.
I have a service bus topic subscription which has messages, When ever new message is placed in subscription, the web application should automatically will pick up and read the messages. I don't have option to implement the same in azure function or event grid.
For example if i implement using azure function, the service bus trigger will automatically pick the new messages and will process.. in the same way i need to implement same functionality/will trigger automatically using web application.
Could you please tell me, how to implement the reading messages using web application .net 6.0 c#.

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73751646/188096.

Comment: @GauravMantri ,the mentioned code will read messages.. but I need, when ever new message is placed in subscription it should automatically pick the code in web application

Comment: See the answer I linked (the one provided by question author and not the accepted answer). It makes use of [`ServiceBusProcessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessor?view=azure-dotnet).